# Electron Code Signing on mac

Tags: build, electron, sign

We are building an electron app on Mac and have enabled code signing with electron-builder like this:

```
npm run pack && electron-builder --mac
```

Can I use the same certificate from apple also for my .exe file (Windows application), or do I need an additional certfificate for this from f.ex comodo, godaddy etc. ?

Ex. does this command below automatically also sign windows files using same certificate generated by apple?

```
npm run pack && electron-builder --win
```

Answer (score 0):

Doesn'n look like that Apple certificate is also working on windows.

I think you have to buy from a provider like comodo or godaddy.

At least my windows application was not successfully signed using:

```
npm run pack && electron-builder --win
```